# Different result of "yyyy/mm/dd" and "yyyy/mm/DD"

Tags: java, date, date-format

I know that to receive date I have to use this code with `dd` in lowercase:

```
DateFormat dateFormat0 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS");
Date dateNow0 = new Date();
System.out.println("Date format: " + dateFormat0.format(dateNow0));
```

and the output is:

*Date format: 2016/28/**06** 09:03:493*

But when I use `DD` in uppercase in date format. code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/DD HH:MM:SS");
Date dateNow1 = new Date();
System.out.println("Date format: " + dateFormat1.format(dateNow1));
```

The output is:

*Date format: 2016/28/**66** 09:03:494*

Why I received different result using capital 'DD' instead of 'dd'?
What the result of 'DD' stands for?

Comment: have a look https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: This stuff isn't exactly secret, get into the habit of RTFM.

Comment: Incredibly lazy question and even got an upvote. Very sad.

Comment: @SSH Thanks, now I see that answer was in documentation.

Comment: By the way, this class is outmoded in Java 8 and later by the java.time classes, specifically [java.time.DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`D` is Day in year (1-365) 
`d` is day in month (1-31)

See the docs on `SimpleDateFormat`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: It should also be mentioned that most of the other pattern symbols of OP are also wrong (changing m versus M or S instead of s).

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution code in Java 7 is:

```
    DateFormat dateFormat3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(dateFormat3.format(cal.getTime()));
```

and in Java 8:

```
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    String text = localDateTime.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(text);
```